# access other host's dictionary variable

Tags: ansible

Assume I have this hosts.yml

```
alpinehosts:
  hosta:
  hostb:
```

Those are hosta's hostvars in ./host_vars/hosta.yml (reverse proxy)

```
rproxyitems:
- rproxyfqdn: "pageA.com"
  comment: "This ia website A"
  rproxyaltfqdn: "alternativeA1.com alternativeA2.com"
  rproxytarget: "http://destinationA"
- rproxyfqdn: "pageB.com"
  comment: "This ia website B"
  rproxyaltfqdn: "alternativeB1.com alternativeBb.com"
  rproxytarget: "http://destinationB"
```

On the host the requests get redirected to I want to have nginx to have server_name just as in reverse proxy. Write once, use many.

That is my destination webhost ./host_vars/hostb.yml (Webserver requests get redirected to)

```
nginxvhost:
- fqdn: pageA.com
  servername: {{ hostvars[hosta].rproxyitems[rproxyfqdn[pageA.com]] }}
  serveraltname: {{ hostvars[hosta].rproxyitems[rproxyfqdn[pageA.com]].rproxyaltfqdn }}
  comment: "This is website A target webservice"
- fqdn: pageB.com
  servername: {{ hostvars[hosta].rproxyitems[rproxyfqdn[pageB.com]] }}
  serveraltname: {{ hostvars[hosta].rproxyitems[rproxyfqdn[pageB.com]].rproxyaltfqdn }}
  comment: "This is website B target webservice"
```

My way doesn't work but I hope you get the idea. How can I just access the other's host (hostA) dictionary variable elements? I could type the values manually of course, but I don't like the concept. I would like to define once, and use often.

For error look at screenshot.[image: error message]

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? I suspect you're getting some errors that will help point out the problem.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just put the text in your question, formatted as a code sample. It looks like you have significant errors in your YAML syntax. The error message you're seeing suggests a solution for several of those problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are quite close to your solution, because `hostvars[hosta].rproxyitems` definitely shows you are on the right track.
But since `pageA.com` and `pageB.com` are values of a list and not keys or a dictionary, this is making your task more complex.

Two solutions for your issue:

1. With your actual list structure, you can use the Jinja filter [`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) and the [`match`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) test of Ansible, to match an element of your list having a specific `rproxyfqdn`: `rproxyitems | selectattr('rproxyfqdn', 'match', 'pageA.com')`. This will return you a list, so if you know for sure you always have only one item matching, just adding a [`first`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#first) filter would do.
   Given the playbook

   ```yaml
   - hosts: hostb
     gather_facts: no

     tasks:
       - debug:
           msg: "{{ nginxvhost }}"
         vars:
           nginxvhost:
             - fqdn: pageA.com
               servername: "{{ (hostvars['hosta'].rproxyitems | selectattr('rproxyfqdn', 'match', 'pageA.com') | first).rproxytarget }}"
               serveraltname: "{{ (hostvars['hosta'].rproxyitems | selectattr('rproxyfqdn', 'match', 'pageA.com') | first).rproxyaltfqdn }}"
               comment: "This is website A target webservice"
             - fqdn: pageB.com
               servername: "{{ (hostvars['hosta'].rproxyitems | selectattr('rproxyfqdn', 'match', 'pageB.com') | first).rproxytarget }}"
               serveraltname: "{{ (hostvars['hosta'].rproxyitems | selectattr('rproxyfqdn', 'match', 'pageB.com') | first).rproxyaltfqdn }}"
               comment: "This is website B target webservice"
   ```

   This gives the recap:

   ```
   PLAY [hostb] ***************************************************

   TASK [debug] ***************************************************
   ok: [hostb] => {
       "msg": [
           {
               "comment": "This is website A target webservice",
               "fqdn": "pageA.com",
               "serveraltname": "alternativeA1.com alternativeA2.com",
               "servername": "http://destinationA"
           },
           {
               "comment": "This is website B target webservice",
               "fqdn": "pageB.com",
               "serveraltname": "alternativeB1.com alternativeBb.com",
               "servername": "http://destinationB"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. You could also slightly change your data structure and use a dictionary instead of a list, making it way easier to access a specific entry:

   ```yaml
   rproxyitems:
     pageA.com:
       comment: "This ia website A"
       rproxyaltfqdn: "alternativeA1.com alternativeA2.com"
       rproxytarget: "http://destinationA"
     pageB.com:
       comment: "This ia website B"
       rproxyaltfqdn: "alternativeB1.com alternativeBb.com"
       rproxytarget: "http://destinationB"
   ```

   Which allow us to a direct access to `rproxyitems['pageA.com']` and makes the playbook simpler:

   ```yaml
   - hosts: hostb
     gather_facts: no

     tasks:
       - debug:
           msg: "{{ nginxvhost }}"
         vars:
           nginxvhost:
             - fqdn: pageA.com
               servername: "{{ hostvars['hosta'].rproxyitems['pageA.com'].rproxytarget }}"
               serveraltname: "{{ hostvars['hosta'].rproxyitems['pageA.com'].rproxyaltfqdn }}"
               comment: "This is website A target webservice"
             - fqdn: pageB.com
               servername: "{{ hostvars['hosta'].rproxyitems['pageB.com'].rproxytarget }}"
               serveraltname: "{{ hostvars['hosta'].rproxyitems['pageB.com'].rproxyaltfqdn }}"
               comment: "This is website B target webservice"
   ```

   This, will give the same recap as above.

Comment: Solution 2 is the EXACT thing I was searching for. Thank you so much.